# Create a .m4s file with ffmpeg

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, mp4, mpeg-dash

I'm rying to create .m4s files and I'm using this command with ffmpeg: `ffmpeg -i input.mov  -c:v copy output.m4s`

The file can't be created.

Output: `Unable to find a suitable output format for tempM4S.m4s tempM4S.m4s: Invalid argument`

I'm guessing the file format .m4s is not supported by ffmpeg which is strange because ffmpeg can create .m4s files when trying to create segments for MPEG-DASH. Is there a workaround this problem? WIll I have to use other tools or check ffmpeg's source code for hints?

Answer (score 1):

m4s files do not work by themselves as they do not contain a moov box required for playback. They require an initialization fragment as well.

Comment: I have an initialization fragment, I just want to create a separate m4s file so I can replace the a segment's content by another one.

Comment: Do you know any sources that I can get that specify this format(m4s)?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to create `m4s` to include it as part of `m4s` series. As @szatmary mentioned, these files are not independent. So you can try this:

1. Merge the `m4s` files to one `mov` file.
2. [Merge](https://superuser.com/questions/1256223/combine-mov-video-files) your `mov` file with the step 1 output file.
3. Split again the output file of step 2 to `m4s` files.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I achieved this. My use case is an audio-only stream. The backend service ships MPEG-DASH files to static hosting. I upload the initializing .mp4 segment once, subsequently only uploading each new .m4s segment.

Also, the playlist .mpd is updated every segment, in order to tell a newly arriving listener where to begin playback. The listener will pick up an initializing .mp4 file for the desired bitrate, followed by the current and following .m4s segments.

- My source material is a series of 10-second media segments in uncompressed .wav format.
- I'll run ffmpeg once per each new media segment
- I've specified a segment size of 11 seconds, to ensure that ffmpeg generates exactly 1 output .m4s segment for each source media segment.

```sh
ffmpeg \
  -i pelicans-1234.wav \
  -f hls \
  -ac 2 \
  -c:a aac \
  -b:a 128k \
  -minrate 128k \
  -maxrate 128k \
  -start_number 1234 \
  -hls_fmp4_init_filename pelicans-128k-IS.mp4 \
  -hls_segment_filename pelicans-128k-%d.m4s \
  -hls_segment_type fmp4 \
  -hls_time 11 \
  temp.m3u8
```

Comment: Update: So far, attempts to ship an MPEG-DASH stream using this method have failed with errors (in VLC) like `mp4: Fragment sequence discontinuity detected 1 != 2` which makes me think that I need to tell ffmpeg what the starting segment number is

Comment: My quest continues in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69625970/java-mp4parser-to-create-a-single-m4s-fragment