# Java mp4parser to create a single .m4s fragment— invalid moov box

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mpeg-dash, mp4parser, fmp4

This use case is a service that manually encodes a series of uncompressed .wav media segments into **.m4s** fragments for broadcast via [MPEG-DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP), using [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) to compress the .wav to .aac
and [sannies/mp4parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser) to assemble the aac audio into an **.m4s** media fragment.

I created [this public GitHub project](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/runs/3936410420?check_suite_focus=true) to reproduce the issue in its entirety.

For example, here's the custom [CustomFragmentMp4Builder.java](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/src/main/java/com/charneykaye/CustomFragmentMp4Builder.java) class.

**It's critical that we be able to designate this single .m4s fragment with a sequence number (index)** that we will manually increment for each media segment.

The objective is to build an **.m4s** fragment comprising the box types `SegmentTypeBox`, `SegmentIndexBox`, and `MovieFragmentBox`. As For reference, I have used *mp4parser* to inspect an **.m4s** fragment that was generated via `ffmpeg -f hls`. This specification is available [here as a .yaml file](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/src/test/resources/test5-128k-151304042-ffmpeg.yaml)

My implementation creates an MP4 without error. But, when the unit test attempts to read the file that the ChunkMp4Builder just wrote to a temp folder:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: A cast to int has gone wrong. Please contact the mp4parser discussion group (3724673092)
    at org.mp4parser.tools.CastUtils.l2i(CastUtils.java:30)
    at org.mp4parser.support.AbstractBox.parse(AbstractBox.java:97)
    at org.mp4parser.AbstractBoxParser.parseBox(AbstractBoxParser.java:116)
    at org.mp4parser.BasicContainer.initContainer(BasicContainer.java:107)
    at org.mp4parser.IsoFile.<init>(IsoFile.java:57)
    at org.mp4parser.IsoFile.<init>(IsoFile.java:52)
    at com.charneykaye.TestBase.getMp4Boxes(TestBase.java:116)
    at com.charneykaye.CustomFragmentMp4BuilderTest.run(CustomFragmentMp4BuilderTest.java:78)
```

The expected box types `SegmentTypeBox`, `SegmentIndexBox`, and `MovieFragmentBox` do appear in the output:

[image: The expected box types SegmentTypeBox, SegmentIndexBox, and MovieFragmentBox do appear in the output]

However, at the end of the file appears a box of an unknown type:

[image: There seems to be a box of an unknown type, appearing at the end of the file.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `m4s` segments are invalid due to an incorrect `mdat` atom size.

For example in `test5-128k-151304042.m4s` the `mdat` is marked as having a length of 16 bytes but there is data at the end and file size is 164884.

The parser then attempts to read an invalid offset. `avc5` is not an atom but actually part of the string "Lavc58.54.100". The length read as 3724673100 is also invalid and greater than the max for a 32-bit integer, hence the invalid cast to int.

[image: hex dump]

---

In your implementation you have:

```
ParsableBox moov = createMovieFragmentBox(movie);
isoFile.addBox(moov);
List<SampleSizeBox> stszs = Path.getPaths(moov, "trak/mdia/minf/stbl/stsz");
// ...

protected MovieFragmentBox createMovieFragmentBox(Movie movie) {
    MovieFragmentBox mfb = new MovieFragmentBox();
    // ...
}
```

This is not a `moov` atom, it's a `moof`. There is no `stsz` in there and the sum of your sample sizes is 0 so the total calculated size of the `mdat` is 16 + 0.

The `moov` is supposed to be in the initialization segment.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to investigate this question! I'll dig into this and likely accept this answer when I'm back at my desk later.

Comment: @CharneyKaye At a glance: [fMP4](https://bitmovin.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/image7.png)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @aergistal https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/pull/1

Comment: Yet, the saga continues! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69684510/java-mp4parser-output-is-empty

Comment: And continues... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69686039/java-mp4parser-fragment-sequence-discontinuity