# Java mp4parser output is empty

Tags: java, mp4, mpeg, mp4parser, fmp4

This use case is a service that manually encodes a series of uncompressed .wav media segments into .m4s fragments for broadcast via MPEG-DASH, using ffmpeg to compress the .wav to .aac and sannies/mp4parser to assemble the aac audio into a .m4s media fragment.

I created [this public GitHub project](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo) to reproduce the issue in its entirety.

For example, here's the custom [ChunkFragmentM4sBuilder.java](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/src/main/java/com/charneykaye/ChunkFragmentM4sBuilder.java) class.

---

The first example using MP4 box works, insofar as I am able to generate an initializing MP4 + series of fragment M4s
files which can then be concatenated to form a playable MPEG4 stream.

Note: it's a requirement for this use case that each media segment is encoded from an individually generated source segment, versus using a tool such as MP4Box to stream from a continuous audio source.

**Attempts to manually build media segments via mp4parser are still failing overall,** because the fragments written by
my [ChunkFragmentM4sBuilder.java](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/src/main/java/com/charneykaye/ChunkFragmentM4sBuilder.java) used below are malformed.
But I'm having a difficult time understanding *how* exactly they are malformed.

It's been helpful for me to compare the two test logs side by
side, [ChunkFragmentM4sBuilderTest.log.txt](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/notes/via-java-mp4parser/ChunkFragmentM4sBuilderTest.log.txt)
and [MP4BoxTest.log.txt](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/notes/via-mp4box/MP4BoxTest.log.txt).

#### via Java mp4parser (malformed)

The former [log](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/notes/via-java-mp4parser/ChunkFragmentM4sBuilderTest.log.txt) is
from [ChunkFragmentM4sBuilderTest.java](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/src/test/java/com/charneykaye/ChunkFragmentM4sBuilderTest.java) which results in
the concatenated test output [test-java-mp4parser.mp4](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/notes/via-java-mp4parser/test-java-mp4parser.mp4) which is in
fact empty:
[image: Concatenated output from Java mp4parser method is empty]

```java
Files.deleteIfExists(Path.of(m4sFilePath));
AACTrackImpl aacTrack=new AACTrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl(aacFilePath));
Movie movie=new Movie();
movie.addTrack(aacTrack);
Container mp4file=new ChunkFragmentM4sBuilder(hz,seconds,seqNum,bufferSize).build(movie);
FileChannel fc=new FileOutputStream(m4sFilePath).getChannel();
mp4file.writeContainer(fc);
fc.close();
```

- [test5.mpd](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/notes/via-java-mp4parser/test5.mpd)
- [test5-128k-163493804.m4s](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/notes/via-java-mp4parser/test5-128k-163493804.m4s)
- [test5-128k-163493805.m4s](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/notes/via-java-mp4parser/test5-128k-163493805.m4s)
- [test5-128k-163493806.m4s](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/notes/via-java-mp4parser/test5-128k-163493806.m4s)
- [test5-128k-IS.mp4](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/notes/via-java-mp4parser/test5-128k-IS.mp4)

Concatenated boxes:

```
FileTypeBox[majorBrand=iso5;minorVersion=512;compatibleBrand=iso6;compatibleBrand=mp41]
MovieBox[MovieHeaderBox[creationTime=Thu Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1903;modificationTime=Thu Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1903;timescale=1000;duration=0;rate=1.0;volume=1.0;matrix=Rotate 0°;nextTrackId=2];TrackBox[TrackHeaderBox[creationTime=Thu Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1903;modificationTime=Thu Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1903;trackId=1;duration=0;layer=0;alternateGroup=1;volume=1.0;matrix=Rotate 0°;width=0.0;height=0.0];EditBox[EditListBox{entries=[Entry{segmentDuration=0, mediaTime=1024, mediaRate=1.0}]}];MediaBox[MediaHeaderBox[creationTime=Thu Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1903;modificationTime=Thu Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1903;timescale=48000;duration=0;language=und];HandlerBox[handlerType=soun;name=SoundHandler];MediaInformationBox[SoundMediaHeaderBox[balance=0.0];DataInformationBox[DataReferenceBox[DataEntryUrlBox[]]];SampleTableBox[SampleDescriptionBox[AudioSampleEntry{bytesPerSample=0, bytesPerFrame=0, bytesPerPacket=0, samplesPerPacket=0, packetSize=0, compressionId=0, soundVersion=0, sampleRate=48000, sampleSize=16, channelCount=2, boxes=[org.mp4parser.boxes.iso14496.part14.ESDescriptorBox@bed094d2]}];TimeToSampleBox[entryCount=0];SampleToChunkBox[entryCount=0];SampleSizeBox[sampleSize=0;sampleCount=0];StaticChunkOffsetBox[entryCount=0]]]]];MovieExtendsBox[org.mp4parser.boxes.iso14496.part12.TrackExtendsBox@11e7301d];UserDataBox[MetaBox[HandlerBox[handlerType=mdir;name=];AppleItemListBox[org.mp4parser.boxes.apple.AppleEncoderBox@691fba4]]]]
SegmentTypeBox[majorBrand=msdh;minorVersion=0;compatibleBrand=msdh;compatibleBrand=msix]
SegmentIndexBox{entries=[Entry{referenceType=0, referencedSize=160944, subsegmentDuration=480000, startsWithSap=1, sapType=0, sapDeltaTime=0}], referenceId=1, timeScale=48000, earliestPresentationTime=0, firstOffset=0, reserved=0}
MovieFragmentBox[MovieFragmentHeaderBox{sequenceNumber=151304042};TrackFragmentBox[TrackFragmentHeaderBox{trackId=1, baseDataOffset=-1, sampleDescriptionIndex=0, defaultSampleDuration=-1, defaultSampleSize=-1, defaultSampleFlags=null, durationIsEmpty=true, defaultBaseIsMoof=true};TrackFragmentBaseMediaDecodeTimeBox{baseMediaDecodeTime=0};TrackRunBox{sampleCount=470, dataOffset=-1, dataOffsetPresent=false, sampleSizePresent=true, sampleDurationPresent=true, sampleFlagsPresentPresent=false, sampleCompositionTimeOffsetPresent=false, firstSampleFlags=null}]]
org.mp4parser.boxes.iso14496.part12.MediaDataBox@3969adb0
```

#### via MP4Box (ok)

The latter [log](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/notes/via-mp4box/MP4BoxTest.log.txt) is
from [MP4BoxTest.java](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/src/test/java/com/charneykaye/MP4BoxTest.java) which results in the concatenated test output
[test-mp4box.mp4](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/notes/via-mp4box/test-mp4box.mp4) which is OK.

Note however, this method is not acceptable for the final use case, because of the imperfections in the blocks that are output by this hack method.

[image: Concatenated output from MP4Box method is ok]

```sh
MP4Box \
  -profile live \
  -add aacFilePath \
  -dash 10000 \
  -frag 10000 \
  -idx ${NUM} \
  -moof-sn ${NUM} \
  -out test5.mpd \
  -segment-name test5-128k- \
  -segment-ext m4s \
  -single-traf \
  -subsegs-per-sidx 0 \
  -daisy-chain \
  -single-segment \
  /tmp
```

- [test5.mpd](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/notes/via-mp4box/test5.mpd)
- [test5-128k-163494320.m4s](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/notes/via-mp4box/test5-128k-163494320.m4s)
- [test5-128k-163494321.m4s](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/notes/via-mp4box/test5-128k-163494321.m4s)
- [test5-128k-163494322.m4s](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/notes/via-mp4box/test5-128k-163494322.m4s)
- [test5-128k-IS.mp4](https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/blob/main/notes/via-mp4box/test5-128k-IS.mp4)

Concatenated boxes:

```
FileTypeBox[majorBrand=iso5;minorVersion=512;compatibleBrand=iso6;compatibleBrand=mp41]
MovieBox[MovieHeaderBox[creationTime=Thu Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1903;modificationTime=Thu Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1903;timescale=1000;duration=0;rate=1.0;volume=1.0;matrix=Rotate 0°;nextTrackId=2];TrackBox[TrackHeaderBox[creationTime=Thu Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1903;modificationTime=Thu Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1903;trackId=1;duration=0;layer=0;alternateGroup=1;volume=1.0;matrix=Rotate 0°;width=0.0;height=0.0];EditBox[EditListBox{entries=[Entry{segmentDuration=0, mediaTime=1024, mediaRate=1.0}]}];MediaBox[MediaHeaderBox[creationTime=Thu Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1903;modificationTime=Thu Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1903;timescale=48000;duration=0;language=und];HandlerBox[handlerType=soun;name=SoundHandler];MediaInformationBox[SoundMediaHeaderBox[balance=0.0];DataInformationBox[DataReferenceBox[DataEntryUrlBox[]]];SampleTableBox[SampleDescriptionBox[AudioSampleEntry{bytesPerSample=0, bytesPerFrame=0, bytesPerPacket=0, samplesPerPacket=0, packetSize=0, compressionId=0, soundVersion=0, sampleRate=48000, sampleSize=16, channelCount=2, boxes=[org.mp4parser.boxes.iso14496.part14.ESDescriptorBox@bed094d2]}];TimeToSampleBox[entryCount=0];SampleToChunkBox[entryCount=0];SampleSizeBox[sampleSize=0;sampleCount=0];StaticChunkOffsetBox[entryCount=0]]]]];MovieExtendsBox[org.mp4parser.boxes.iso14496.part12.TrackExtendsBox@7ce1e496];UserDataBox[MetaBox[HandlerBox[handlerType=mdir;name=];AppleItemListBox[org.mp4parser.boxes.apple.AppleEncoderBox@51da5351]]]]
SegmentTypeBox[majorBrand=msdh;minorVersion=0;compatibleBrand=msdh;compatibleBrand=msix]
SegmentIndexBox{entries=[Entry{referenceType=0, referencedSize=162267, subsegmentDuration=479232, startsWithSap=1, sapType=1, sapDeltaTime=0}], referenceId=1, timeScale=48000, earliestPresentationTime=0, firstOffset=0, reserved=0}
MovieFragmentBox[MovieFragmentHeaderBox{sequenceNumber=151304042};TrackFragmentBox[TrackFragmentHeaderBox{trackId=1, baseDataOffset=-1, sampleDescriptionIndex=0, defaultSampleDuration=-1, defaultSampleSize=-1, defaultSampleFlags=null, durationIsEmpty=false, defaultBaseIsMoof=true};TrackFragmentBaseMediaDecodeTimeBox{baseMediaDecodeTime=0};TrackRunBox{sampleCount=468, dataOffset=1964, dataOffsetPresent=true, sampleSizePresent=true, sampleDurationPresent=false, sampleFlagsPresentPresent=false, sampleCompositionTimeOffsetPresent=false, firstSampleFlags=null}]]
org.mp4parser.boxes.iso14496.part12.MediaDataBox@640d3ba5
```

Comment: This is a continuation of my quest from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69625970/java-mp4parser-to-create-a-single-m4s-fragment-invalid-moov-box/

Comment: This isn't properly an answer to the question, ***but*** I was able to resolve the issue by rebuilding my ChunkFragmentM4sBuilder class from Sebastian Annies FragmentedMp4Builder instead of his DefaultMp4Builder class (from the original mp4parser builders)

    https://github.com/charneykaye/encode-fmp4-demo/commit/b90f05d6eb59dd1ad6394df40479f36347846dcb

Comment: The saga continues... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69686039/java-mp4parser-fragment-sequence-discontinuity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test-java-mp4parser.mp4` is not empty but is invalid because:

- the `sidx` entry referenced size is wrong
- the `tfhd` is overriding the default sample description index (`1`) with `0`
- the `trun` doesn't specify the data offset
- the `mdat` AAC data starts with 8 zero bytes which cause the decoding to fail

The file plays with FFmpeg if these are fixed.

The `m4s` segments listed are also malformed and don't seem to correspond to the concatenation result. For example the sequence number is used as the sample description index.